# Вывод отсортированного списка файлов

Tags: c#, winforms, сортировка

Первый раз работаю с WF и вот тут получил такое задание: нужно создать программу (не консольную), где я должен:

1. Выбрать любую  папку с подпапками и файлами, и список файлов и подпапок будет выведен в listBox, textBox или куда можно.
2. **А вот второе задание - это чтобы в этом самом listBox, textBox или куда там выводим содержание папки, можно было сортировать по дате создания, по размеру и по типу файла.**

Самое сложное тут - 2-й пункт. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Для списка с колонками вам нужен [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx). Устанавливаете режим просмотра в свойстве `View` в `Details`, устанавливаете список колонок и добавляете записи с несколькими полями (имя, дата создания, размер и т.д.). Сортировка задается через свойство `Sorting`.
Пример кода для отображения списка файлов (только имена):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

Дальше сами разберетесь, в приведенной ссылке на MSDN пример хороший.

Comment: А как этот код подставить под команду private void CreateFolderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  ?